# Unexpected number relations

Tags: mathematics

Let's have the following numbers:

$ \sqrt{\frac{2069}{24}}$, $11$, $\frac{1397}{24}$, $ \sqrt{\frac{2069}{24}}$, $3$, $\frac{2741}{24}$,$13$, $\sqrt{\frac{2069}{24}}$, $91$.

<sub>**Transcription**: square root of two-thousand and sixty-nine over twenty-four, then eleven, then one thousand three hundred and ninety-seven over twenty-four, then the square root of two-thousand and sixty-nine over twenty-four, then three, then two thousand seven hundred and forty-one over twenty-four, then thirteen, then the square root of two-thousand and sixty-nine over twenty-four, then ninety-one.</sub>

How are these numbers related?

HINT: If you group all these numbers in the right way, then you should be able to solve the equation $A^3=B^3+C^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how one would go about finding this without the hint but searching through the possibilities, it seems the following holds

> $$ \left( \frac{1397}{24} + 3 \sqrt{\frac{2069}{24}}\right)^3 + \left( 91 + 13 \sqrt{\frac{2069}{24}}\right)^3 = \left( \frac{2741}{24} + 11\sqrt{\frac{2069}{24}}\right)^3$$

which, I think, is the desired relationship.

Comment: This is the correct answer.